# #error need to prove a real asm/page.h

Tags: c

When I include the file below:

```
include <asm-generic/page.h>
```

And compile the c file, the error appears:

```
include/asm-generic/page.h:9:2: error: #error need to prove a real asm/page.h
```

how to solve that problem?

Comment: Are you building code for an embedded target with no MMU ?

Comment: No, build code for x86 Linux

Comment: So why are you including `<asm-generic/page.h>` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#include` the correct `page.h` for your target architecture. If it's x86 then this would be:

```
#include <asm-x86/page.h>
```

Comment: I find the problem:

I should include the file:

    #include <asm/pgtable_types.h>
    #include <asm/pgtable.h>

which is in /arch/x86/include

not the file:

    #include <asm-generic/page.h>

Answer (score 0):

The real asm/page.h refers to

```
arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h
arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h
```

after include these two files, it is OK